# how to handle swipe gestures from the bottom of the screen

Tags: objective-c, ios

i have an application with three screens and i want to display and hide a small uiview when the user swipes from the bottom of the ipad screen towards up. I know that this cannot be down with normal swipe gestures. I was wondering if you could tell me how to handle these kinds of swipe gestures?

Answer (score 5):

Add UIPanGestureRecognizer to your view.

```
-(void) panDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer *) gesture 
{    
    BOOL fromBottom = NO;
    CGPoint loc = [gesture locationInView:self.view];

    if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {                  
       if(loc is somewhere in the bottom of view)
            fromBottom = YES;
    }
    else if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        // You can up your view with finger movement here


    }
    else if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking Swipe... I was so wrong... Swipe are very hard to trigger on a small-sized view. Pan seems like the best solution if you want to recognize gestures on a small-sized view.